# How to make a Haskell suprocess called from Python to not close after one use?

Tags: python, haskell, subprocess, eof

I have a simple .exe file compiled from Haskell that just prints to stdout everything it receives to stdin:

```
module Main where

main = do
  command <- getLine
  putStrLn command
  main
```

And I have a Python file that tries to send two lines to the subprocess:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

p = Popen(['main.exe'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)  

def send_command(arg):
    print("Sending command: "+arg)  
    response = p.communicate(input=arg)[0].decode()
    print("Response: "+response+"\n")
    return response

send_command("Test1")
send_command("Test2")
```

It works the first time around, but not the second, apparently because it considers the input completed:

```
Sending command: Test1
Response: Test1
main.exe: <stdin>: hGetLine: end of file


Sending command: Test2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\test.py", line 12, in <module>
    send_command("Test2")
  File ".\test.py", line 7, in send_command
    response = p.communicate(input=arg)[0].decode()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 483, in communicate
    return self._communicate(input)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 722, in _communicate
    self.stdin.write(input)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

I don't know if the fault lies with Python or Haskell; other subprocesses for as expected when called from Python, and the Haskell file works as expected when called from the command line, but they just refuse to work together. How to fix this?

**Edit:**

I replaced the `communicate` with direct read\write:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

p = Popen(['main.exe'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)  

def send_command(arg):
    print("Sending command: "+arg)  
    p.stdin.write(arg+"\n")
    response = p.stdout.readline().decode()
    print("Response: "+response+"\n")
    return response

send_command("Test1")
send_command("Test2")
```

And made sure (just in case) that the .exe properly terminates lines:

```
module Main where

main = do
  command <- getLine
  putStrLn (command ++ "\n")
  main
```

And now the program just stops and does nothing at this point:

```
Sending command: Test1
```

Am I supposed to somehow "flush" the input or what?

Comment: The `communicate` actually does that, since it passes the input, and closes its side of the input channel.

Comment: What should I use instead of communicate if I want to keep interacting with the subprocess?

Comment: you write to the `.stdin` of the process, and you read from the `.stdout` of the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the documentation for the [`subprocess.Popen.communicate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) function you're calling:

> Popen.communicate(input=None, timeout=None)
>
> Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached. **Wait for process to terminate**.

(my emphasis).

You can just write to `p.stdin` and read from `p.stdout` if you don't want all the other stuff `communicate` does.

> I don't know if the fault lies with Python or Haskell

This isn't intended as a criticism, but a helpful hint: the fault lies with whoever didn't read the documentation for the function they called. It's free, read it!

Comment: Yes, the input/output streams are both probably buffered. You can call `p.stdin.flush()` on the Python side - the doc for `Popen.stdin` links to `open()` which links to the built-in file type, which links to the [`io`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.flush) module. I don't know how Haskell behaves here.

Comment: @user2649762, on the Haskell side, I'm not sure what the default buffering is in this case. It might be `LineBuffering`, in which case you should be okay. If you're still having trouble, you should import `System.IO`. Then you can explicitly flush stdout on the Haskell side using `hFlush stdout`, or you can call `hSetBuffering stdout LineBuffering` or `hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering` to modify the buffering globally. You probably only want `NoBuffering` in special circumstances, since its performance will be lousy if you make many small writes.